# Find element inside array and return only array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB, so i'm having some newbie problems.

I have this document on DB

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5a7ba73dbf27878474ac7682"),
"Enterprise" : "SpaceX",
"Address" : "qwerty",
"users" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Elon",
        "number" : "123456",
        "email" : "elon@mars.com",
        "user" : "elon",
        "pass" : "byeroadster"
    }, 
    {
        "name" : "Larry",
        "number" : "3215465",
        "email" : "larry@google.com",
        "user" : "larry",
        "pass" : "googlepassword"
    }
]
```

}

And i'm doing this query

```
var db = client.db('hauz_manager');
    var findUser = db.collection('system_enterprise');
    findUser.find({'users.user': data.user},{contatos: 1}).toArray(function(err, result){
      console.log(result.users);
    });
```

With that, i'm having like

```
Enterprise: "SpaceX"
...
users: [{Object}]
```

And, i'm not able to do some result.users, returns undefined.

tnx.

Comment: what is contatos ? cant see any such field in your document

Comment: Use mongoose, your life will be simpler

Comment: I'm sorry, where is 'contatos', read users, i forgot to change.

Comment: Np. Try `findUser.find({'users.user': data.user},{users: 1}).toArray(function(err, result){       console.log(result.users);`

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(result.users)
```

I think your callback return array.
You should check callback.
Do you need a loop?